# Xcode: Storyboard Tabbed Application Passing Data Back and Forth

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitextfield, storyboard

I am currently using the following code to try to pass the text in a UITextField between 3 view controllers that are looking at the same ViewController.h and ViewController.m files:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NameOfSegue"]) {
        ViewController *ibcVC = segue destinationViewController;
        ibcVC.myTextField = self.myTextField;
    }
}
```

I have 3 view controllers linked in the following order: ***ViewC1 => ViewC2 => ViewC3.***

**My UITextField is on ViewC2.**

When I click on the button on **ViewC2** for example, that Pushes in **ViewC3**, it passes the data just fine to **ViewC3**. However, say I am currently on **ViewC2**, I type something in the UITextView, and I next click on the Back button on the Navigation that Xcode automatically puts there when working with tabbed view applications, it will take me to **ViewC1** just fine as expected. However, if I push the button on ViewC1 that Pushes in **ViewC2**, the Data/Text I typed in my UITextField has been erased or reset to null.

So basically here is the problem using a slight digital visual:

*DATA IS PUSHED CORRECTLY EX.*

**ViewC1 => ViewC2 => ViewC3**

*DATA IS ERASED IF WE PRESS THE BACK BUTTON ON NAVIGATION EX.*

**ViewC1 <= ViewC2**

Comment: what method are you using to go back to viewc1? dismissmodalviewcontroller?

Comment: You do not have to use one. Xcode automatically makes a back button in the Navigation when you use the Tabbed Application and link view controllers with the Push Segue. I'm using Storyboard for that part, so everything is done in the IB and no programming is needed when dealing with pushing and etc. But yes, if I knew what Xcode was doing with that part I could probably figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to store your string in a singleton.

SharedStrings.h =

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SharedStrings : NSObject{
    NSString *string;
}

+(SharedStrings *)sharedString;
-(void)setString:(NSString *)newString;
-(NSString *)getString;

@end
```

SharedStrings.m =

```
#import "SharedStrings.h"

static SharedStrings *sharedString;

@implementation SharedStrings

-(id)init{

    self = [super init];
    string = [NSString new];
    return self;
}

+(SharedStrings *)sharedString{
    if (!sharedString) {
        sharedString = [[SharedStrings alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedString;
}

-(void)setString:(NSString *)newString{
    string = newString;
}
-(NSString *)getString{
    return string;
}

@end
```

You could then have all your views get and set the string as necessary, like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [myTextField setText:[[SharedStrings sharedString] getString]];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (textField == enterInfoTF) {
        [[SharedStrings sharedString] setString:textField.text];
    }
}
```