# Xcode - how to pass the value of 1 variable from first view controller to another view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode: Storyboard Tabbed Application Passing Data Back and Forth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661246/xcode-storyboard-tabbed-application-passing-data-back-and-forth)

Basically I have 2 view controllers

1st view controller : contains table view

2nd view controller: contains image view

I want to load the image on 2nd view controller based upon the value selected from table view (from 1st view contrller)

I know I can capture the value of selected cell using following code

```
NSString *CellVal = [[NSString alloc]init];
CellVal = [exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

but how do I refer the value of "CellVal" in 2nd View conroller ?

Comment: You don't need to do `[[NSString alloc] init];` this create an immutable empty string, which is pretty useless. If you are not using ARC then this is also a memory leak.

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9690731/542400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a NSString property in your second controller.  Then, at some point, use something like `secondController.stringProperty = cellVal;`.

The place where you put the code you posted and that assignment depends on whether you are using xib files or a storyboard.  In one case, you would do it where you initialize the second controller from a nib and otherwise you would do it in prepareForSegue: (using the destination controller from the seque).