# How to pass data between viewcontrollers in tabbed applications?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have found 2 methods but am wondering if there's a better solution with xcode 5.

1. [How to Pass Data Between iOS Tab bar Using Protocol and delegate](http://enroyed.com/ios/how-to-pass-data-between-ios-tab-bars-using-delegate/)
2. [Xcode: Storyboard Tabbed Application Passing Data Back and Forth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661246/xcode-storyboard-tabbed-application-passing-data-back-and-forth)

Tried printing a `NSLog` in `prepareForSegue` but it doesn't even get called?

What is the current best practice to pass data between viewcontrollers for tabbed applications using storyboard and with io6 support?

Comment: Do you want to pass the data forward or backward?

Comment: @Rashad I would like to know both.

Comment: Use protocol / delegate, as prepareForSegue is for navigationController.

Comment: check out UITabBarControllerDelegate method tabBarController:didSelectViewController:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [iPhone: How to Pass Data Between Several Viewcontrollers in a Tabbar App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363777/iphone-how-to-pass-data-between-several-viewcontrollers-in-a-tabbar-app)

Also the imho cleanest way is to use the NSNotificationcenter. It's simple: [How to use NSNotificationcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)

Comment: I decided to go with the using AppDelegate method since data passed is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

singleton is a good idea. You can also do it by using AppDelegate. If your data is not huge you can store your data in AppDelegate and access those from any viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

I have used delegate approach from 1. I wanted to pass data between third and second view controller so I just added this into third view controller viewDidLoad to catch if user goes to third tab after the tab bar starts in the first view controller

```
SecondViewController *svc = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
self.delegate = svc;
```